# OpsCenter API return all null values for os-cpu-* metrics

Tags: opscenter

Invoking the metrics API (e.g., /cluster/metrics/node/os-cpu-idle?start=1397746020&function=average), I get all null values:

```
{
  "192.168.4.101": {
    "AVERAGE": [
      [
        1397746020,
        null
      ],
      [
        1397746080,
        null
      ],
. . .
      [
        1397746440,
        null
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

The same goes for all os-cpu-* metrics. Other metrics, like memory, disk, network, etc., return valid values.

There are no cpu/proc-related errors in the agent log. Appreciate any insights.

Comment: Do the CPU graphs in the UI also show "NO DATA"?  Trying to determine if it's an issue with the data or your API call

Comment: The CPU graphs are completely blank, for all CPU metrics (user/nice/system/steal, etc.). They do not show the "NO DATA" label.

Comment: What OS platform/flavor/version/etc are your nodes on?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Server (VirtualBox)

Comment: We haven't done any official testing on Ubuntu 14.04, so it's possible there is an incompatibility with how the agent is parsing iostat.  Can you paste the output of "iostat -c -m 1 2" somewhere that will retain the formatting and link here?  You can also set the log level of the agent to TRACE to get some additional logging around how the agent is running that command and parsing it.